# regular expression "\xa0" in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

html:

```
<div>数量：100-200个&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

I want to get `100-200个`.

analysis：

```
response.xpath('/html/body/div/text()').re_first('数量：(.+)\s$')
```

result：

```
100-200个\xa0\xa0\xa0
```

There are 4 `&nbsp` in html,and there are 3 `\xa0` in the result,I want to get `100-200个` only ,not contain the 3 `\xa0`,how to modify the regular expression in `re_first('数量：(.+)\s$')`?

Comment: `数量：(.+个)`? why do you have a `\s` when there doesn't seem to be any whitespace after the div

Comment: This should do the trick. `response.xpath('/html/body/div/text()').re_first('数量：(.+)?&nbsp.*$')` but your usecase seems very specific to this text. you might run into similar problems if you dont build a more generic regex.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case seems very specific to this text. You might run into similar problems with different text. if you don't build a more generic regex.

Following code will solve your problem:

```
import re

a = """<div>数量：100-200个&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>"""

m = re.search('数量：(.+?)\&.*$',a)

m.group(1)
```

output:

```
'100-200个'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should work outside the regex using something like:

```
response.xpath('/html/body/div/text()').re_first('数量：(.+)\s$').strip()
```